# Rename files using Bash

Tags: bash, regex

I know this has been asked before but I'm specifically having trouble renaming the following files in my directory

```
"1.file1" 
"2.file2"
"3.file3"
```

to

```
"1 file1"
"2 file2"
"3 file3"
```

using simple Bash/regex. Double quotes are not parts of file names; they are included because of the spaces in the new file names. I've tried something like `for x in [0-9]\.*; do mv` but get stuck because I need to repeat the same number that was found at the beginning of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing your approach:

```
for x in [0-9].*; do mv -i "$x" "${x/./ }"; done
```

Note there is no regex here. `[0-9].*` is a [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) (where `.` is not special). `${x/./ }` [expands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) the `x` variable and replaces the first `.` with space.

Notes:

- `[0-9]` matches exactly one character. Names starting with `12.` will not match.
- `[0-9]` is locale dependent (`LC_COLLATE`). I don't expect surprises, but still.
- I used `-i` in case there are files with desired names in the directory already.